# What's the best tradeoff between text and icons on buttons?

Tags: text, usability, icons

In a discussion with co-workers today, I lamented that I can't ever remember what an icon means, and have to hover over them to see the tooltips, and thus to find the button I need.

On their side, they were saying that when the text needs to be translated, it might not fit (German vs English for example), and that every place where there is text, including tooltips, it needs a translation.  So plain icons are easier.

What is the best tradeoff in useability for the extra work of text vs the subset of users who are icon-challanged?

Comment: I'm just wondering if it would be better to move some of these older questions to more appropriate stackexchange sites, rather than just closing them.  At the time they were asked, the other sites didn't exist, but the voting indicates that it's not a bad question, just one that no longer fits the tighter definition of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I personally prefer text and **hate** icon-only UI's.  I know that other people think the other way, equally strongly, either because of internationalization or because their brain works more rapidly with images than with text.  If you choose one or the other exclusively for your UI, then part of your user base will be unhappy with your choice.  (Sometimes this is the right choice, depending on how extensively the UI will be used.)

Internationalization is really not that difficult, except for finding a firm to do good translations of your text.  The programmer portion of internationalization is pretty straightforward.  However, I've known a number of programmers who prefer the all-icon method as it's less work.  I've personally had to replace one all-icon-no-text UI that the users didn't like.  The users said they could not remember what the icons meant.

I think more typically, many advanced users will prefer icons and many beginning users will prefer text.  However, a number of advanced users prefer text.  IMHO, any good UI will provide tooltips, so you need to translate your interface no matter what you do.

The most friendly solution is to offer both text and icons, possibly with a settings choice to disable one or the other.

Comment: +1. Hit all my pet peeve points. Once you work out what an Icon means you don't need the text so much, but tooltips are helpful for when you forget.

Answer (score 2):

I worked with people in a Human/Computer Interactions group and was raked over the coals for using icon-only.  They had studies about comprehension, error rate, and speed of using UI's and a good icon/label combination won every time, all else being equal.

Localization should be a non-issue.  You may have to localize the icons anyway and localizing a label (as long as it's stored as text and not as bits) is easy.  In terms of size in the UI - that's another matter entirely.  If you can't fit the text, I'd claim that your UI is too cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

Really they both have advantages and draw backs.  Text must always be translated into different langugues, and sometimes a single word will not be able to effectively describe the action of a button.  For example, how would you describe the X button which closes a window in Windows.  We know what it does, and most people I know call it the X button, but it doesn't describe what it does.  It's a lot easier to put a button with an X symbol (or icon if you will) than put something like "close window".

That being said icons also have drawbacks.  As you eluded they may not always be clear what they do.  The user has to be able to put the icon in a social context to understand what it does.  This may not always be possible.  Also, icons in one language may not be understood in another, leading back to the translation problem.   Icons can be advantageous in certain areas as they can take a complex concept and show the user with a small amount of space.  (like to take a picture show a camera, or delete something showing trash can).

The trade off is really in a case by case basis.  If you have power users who really understand the application they are using and the surrounding subject, you are probably ok with using them.  If you have people who use computers once a month and don't really care to learn it is going to be confusing.  Its the amount of information you can convey with a single symbol (icon, picture, letter) vs. the potential frustration of the users and the overall rejection of your program.

Comment: I use computers daily, but not all applications daily.  And I'll use 5-15 different applications at a time.  I simply can't remember what the "refresh" button looks like on the different applications.  Thus hovering over to see the tooltips.  It's not just a "power user" vs noobie issue.

Comment: I can see what you are saying about not focusing enough time to learn the icons, but I would bet there are some that you just know.  Also, ironically I bet the tool tips are preventing you from learning what the icons are.  You don't have a reason to remember them, so you mind doesn't commit them.

Comment: @kevin: you *do* have a reason, speed, the delay waiting for the tooltip is annoying :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a way to get both.  Screen readers have a horrible time with icons.

Answer (score 1):

I hate icons, because I never know what they mean even if they're perfectly intuitive (like this world icon that means hyperlink above this box in which I'm typing). Several Unix terminal applications provide a choice between:

- text
- graphical icons
- both

That's nice. I usually like the text on a prominent button, because the meaning of the button is much more clear and the mouse target can be a little bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Its a cultural thing as some symbols (icons) mean different things to people of different cultures, backgrounds and experiences. There are global symbols that one could assume to be 'known' by the general population, i.e. the 'save' icon...

It is a fine line, but i think the tooltips are a good way to help out those who dont understand the meaning of the icon. Perhaps a set of options to have the buttons (icons) render with text instead of the icon image ? This could be a user preference in the application.

Perhaps a good reference would be some of the "extensively" used icons in microsoft applications such as 'Word'. I am generalising here, but microsoft applications are almost eveywhere and they have done all the R&D into suitable / effective icons.

Comment: What *is* the "Save" icon?  A floppy disk?  (I had to go check -- yes, it is in fact a floppy disk in my version of MS Word.)  With floppy drives no longer even being included on most new machines, I wonder, will users still recognize what that icon means 10 years from now?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if this is for a web application, but if it is then you have to provide the text at least as a backup if the user has disabled images, is using a screen reader, or other limited interface.

Answer (score 0):

two things i guess

1. the decision should be the result of usability research and properly quantified, rather than a dev's gut feel or whim.
2. an icon that doesn't carry an obvious meaning is a bad icon and should be changed.

all that said, IMO: Icons with a tooltip/mouseover text equivalent, with bonus that this can carry a reminder of the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I use "button" here to mean "the UI element on which the icon and/or text is located.")

I think in almost all cases it's important to include text either on the button itself, or at least on a hover-over tooltip on the button, so that in the event that the icon's meaning isn't intuitive to a particular user, the user can find out the meaning by reading the text.  (Note that the translation work still needs to be performed in either case.)

A typical case for not including text directly on the button itself is when *space is at a premium*; when you want to fit a lot of buttons into a small area.  Examples include the "toolbars" used in many desktop applications, and also in some web applications -- for example, the buttons that appear just above the StackOverflow answer text entry field!

A good case for including icons is when the button *doesn't always appear in the same place*, and the user would benefit from being able to quickly visually scan for where the button is located.  For example, if I have a lot of programs open on Windows and I want to quickly find my instance of Firefox in the Windows taskbar, I'll look for the little orange icon, rather than reading the text on each taskbar button.